# A linked node that has 2 items in a single node

Tags: c++, nodes

How can I create a linked node so that each linked node contains 2 items in a single node? Im not sure if I'm going in the right direction. I have 2 private members in my class, and I'm not sure if I need 2 set functions or if I can have a single set function with 2 parameters. For example `void setItem(const string& anItem, const string secondItem);`

```
#ifndef _NODE
#define _NODE
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
private:
   string item; // A data item
   Node* next; // Pointer to next node

public:
   Node();
   Node(const string& anItem);
   Node(const string& anItem, Node* nextNodePtr);
   void setItem(const string& anItem);
   void setNext(Node* nextNodePtr);
   string getItem() const ;
   Node* getNext() const ;
}; // end Node

#include "Node.cpp"
#endif
```

This is my Node.cpp file:

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

Node::Node() : next(nullptr)
{
} // end default constructor

Node::Node(const string& anItem) : item(anItem),  next(nullptr)
{
} // end constructor

Node::Node(const string& anItem, Node* nextNodePtr) :
            item(anItem), next(nextNodePtr)
{
} // end constructor

void Node::setItem(const string& anItem)
{
   item = anItem;

} // end setItem

void Node::setNext(Node* nextNodePtr)
{
   next = nextNodePtr;
} // end setNext

string Node::getItem() const
{
   return item;
} // end getItem


Node* Node::getNext() const
{
   return next;
} // end getNext
```

Comment: You should not `#include "Node.cpp"` and avoid `using namespace std;` in header.

Comment: Unless it is for homework, you may consider `std::list<std::pair<std::string, string>>` or replacing `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` by a proper `struct`

Comment: @Jarod42 its exactly for hw, I want to have a linked list that contains 2 items per node because the bigger picture is that I need to store a key and value in the list since I am dealing with a dictionary ADT. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: You can have `setItem1` and `setItem2`, or `setItems`, or both. The question is how this code is to be used, and specifically how often one item will be changed and not the other.

Comment: @Jarod42 I have a pair class that contains 2 private data items but I don't know how i can make the pair class work with my list class and node class. My list class is used to add, remove, find data etc

Comment: @Beta Lets say that I have a arbitrary add function from my class called list and wanted to add 2 data items into the list how would my add function be defined? This is what I have but doesn't seem to work when compiled. <br>
void List::insert(string data, string data2){

        Node* newptr = new Node (data, data2); //create new node
        newptr->setItem(data); 
        newptr->setItem2(data2);
        newptr->setNext(headPtr); //sets the ptr to headptr(null)
        headPtr = newptr; //headptr points to the node you've just created
        size++; //increment the size
}

<br/>

Comment: @programmingblues Shouldn't you let the previous node to point to your new node? And where are you inserting the new node in the linked list?

Comment: @SeanBallais im inserting the new node at the front. do you know what you're talking about?

Comment: I know. I misread your comment. I'm sorry. I'm already sleepy at the time of writing so some part of my brain might have thought that you're inserting in the middle and didn't realize that your code was inserting from the front. My bad. :(

Comment: You pass the two strings to the `Node` constructor, so there's no reason to pass them *again* through `setItem` and `setItem2`, but I don't see why it "doesn't seem to work". Can you give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem?

Comment: @Jarod42  
Thanks. Based on your answer below,  Im not sure how you'll define your copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor. Do you mind helping me out?

Comment: @programmingblues: The simpler should be to delete copy/assignment (correct but restrict usage of List...).If your destructor have to delete `next` (that's mean that List has ownership node which is the more common case), copy constructor has to make a deep copy of node (not copy pointer, but create new nodes), in addition assignment should delete its content. If your destructor doesn't have to delete `next` (then who owns the resource ?), then default destructor/copy/assignment should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I'd go for two public functions for setting the two items of the node. One function will modify only one item, while the other function will modify the two item. Like:

```
// Function that will only set one item
void Node::setIndexItem(const int propNum, const string val)
{
    if (propNum == 1) { // You may use 0 for the first item
        this.item = val;
    } else if (propNum == 2) { // You may use 1 for the second item
        this.item2 = val;
    } else {
        // You may want to raise an exception here. Depends on you really.
    }
}

// Function that will set the two items
void Node::setItems(const string val1, const string val2)
{
    this.item = val1;
    this.item2 = val2;
}
```

Comment: I would avoid `setIndexItem` which may be used with error whereas alternative like 2 methods is safer and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would create a dedicated class for the data

```
struct DataNode
{
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
};
```

That separates class responsabilities (*List* may be focussed to link node).
That would allow you to modify *data* type without changing your class List (a templated list would be even better, but out of scope).

And then, your Node class would be something like:

```
class Node
{
private:
   DataNode data;
   Node* next; // Pointer to next node // I assume you can't use unique_ptr :-/
public:
   Node();
   Node(const DataNode& data);
   Node(const DataNode& data, Node* nextNodePtr);

   // Rule of 3
   Node(const Node& rhs);
   ~Node();
   Node& operator =(const Node& rhs);

   // data accessor
   void setItem(const DataNode& data);
   const DataNode& getItem() const;
   DataNode& getItem();

   // Internal utility
   void setNext(Node* nextNodePtr);
   const Node* getNext() const;
   Node* getNext();
};
```

I added a non-const version of the getter to allow modifying part of the item:

```
node.getItem().value = "new value";
```